# How to replace multiple overlapping patterns with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace all occurrences of `&&` with `and`.

For example, `x&& && &&` should become `x&& and and`.

I tried `re.sub(' && ', ' and ', 'x&& && && ')`, but it didn't work, the first `&&` already consumed the whitespace so the second one didn't match.

Then I thought of non-capturing group and tried but failed again.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))&&(?=\s|$)
```

Use `lookarounds`.Do not consume `space` just `assert`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/39

```
re.sub('(?:^|(?<=\s))&&(?=\s|$)', 'and', 'x&& && &&')
```

Output:`'x&& and and'`

Comment: the output of this code is `'x&& and and '`, not `'x&& and and'`

Comment: @pabtorre there was a typo.check now

Answer (score 3):

You could use non-word boundaries here.

```
>>> re.sub(r'\B&&\B', 'and', 'x&& && &&')
'x&& and and'
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a very old post. Anyone looking for alternative can use the following regex as well.

```
re.sub(r"(\s)(\&\&)(?=(\s))", r"\1and", a)
```